# my application crashed when i start and launching?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

```
2020-01-23 10:51:40.910 5891-5891/com.thomas.mirakle.crm_mirakle E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.thomas.mirakle.crm_mirakle, PID: 5891
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thomas.mirakle.crm_mirakle/com.thomas.mirakle.crm_mirakle.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/AppleMyungjo.ttf
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2825)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2886)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1623)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:186)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6509)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:804)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/AppleMyungjo.ttf
        at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromAsset(Typeface.java:269)
        at com.thomas.mirakle.crm_mirakle.MainActivity.resource(MainActivity.java:435)
        at com.thomas.mirakle.crm_mirakle.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:107)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6992)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2886) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1623) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:186) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6509) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:804)
```

[image]

Comment: It can not find font named AppleMyungio.ttf. Find where you have used that font and replace it OR define the font properly.

Comment: please add your code as text, not as images. that makes it easier for people here to copy paste over :)

Comment: It's not able to find the font fonts/AppleMyungjo.ttf. Check if you added this font in res-->font-->AppleMyungjo.ttf

Comment: Font asset not found fonts/AppleMyungjo.ttf

Comment: > Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font asset not found fonts/AppleMyungjo.ttf

Comment: File->invalidate cache/ restart

Answer (score 0):

add AppleMyungjo.ttf in your assets  in your app like this [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have directly copy/paste your font AppleMyungjo.ttf in assets folder. 
try creating fonts folder inside assets and then paste your font AppleMyungjo.ttf inside that.
hope this will help.